# Lambda Gives an error { "errorMessage": "Process exited before completing request" }

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying to execute this lambda function and getting error "{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 6db7d67e-78e9-43e5-a325-09206e4514ac Process exited before completing request"
}
"

I am looking the script to notify the AWS IAM Users when their password and access keys expire.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import os
import json
import csv
from time import sleep
import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import sys


# These should be passed in via Lambda Environment Variables
try: 
    BLACKHOLE_GROUPNAME = os.environ['BLACKHOLE_GROUPNAME']
    ACTION_TOPIC_ARN = os.environ['ACTION_TOPIC_ARN']
    GRACE_PERIOD = int(os.environ['GRACE_PERIOD'])
    DISABLE_USERS = os.environ['DISABLE_USERS']
    SEND_EMAIL = os.environ['SEND_EMAIL']
    FROM_ADDRESS = os.environ['FROM_ADDRESS']
    EXPLANATION_FOOTER = os.environ['EXPLANATION_FOOTER']
    EXPLANATION_HEADER = os.environ['EXPLANATION_HEADER']
except KeyError as e:
    print("Key Error: " + e.message)
    sys.exit(1)


# Define a Global String to be the report output sent to ACTION_TOPIC_ARN
ACTION_SUMMARY = ""
REPORT_SUMMARY = ""

print('Loading function')

if DISABLE_USERS == "true":
    expired_message = "\n\tYour Password is {} days post expiration. Your permissions have been revoked. "
    key_expired_message = "\n\tYour AccessKey ID {} is {} days post expiration. It has been deactivated. "
else:    
    expired_message = "\n\tYour Password is {} days post expiration. You must change your password or risk losing access. "
    key_expired_message = "\n\tYour AccessKey ID {} is {} days post expiration. You must rotate this key or it will be deactivated. "

key_warn_message = "\n\tYour AccessKey ID {} is {} days from expiration. You must rotate this key or it will be deactivated. "
password_warn_message = "\n\tYour Password will expire in {} days"

email_subject = "Credential Expiration Notice From AWS Account: {}"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, sort_keys=True))
    iam_client = boto3.client('iam')

    try: 
        if event['source'] == "aws.iam" : 
            process_IAMEvent(event, context, iam_client)
        else:
            process_UsersCron(iam_client)
    except KeyError as e:
        # Probably called as a test event with out a source. This is what we want to do here. 
        process_UsersCron(iam_client)
    return

def process_UsersCron(iam_client): 
    global ACTION_SUMMARY # This is what we send to the admins
    global REPORT_SUMMARY
    max_age = get_max_password_age(iam_client)
    account_name = iam_client.list_account_aliases()['AccountAliases'][0]
    credential_report = get_credential_report(iam_client)

    # Iterate over the credential report, use the report to determine password expiration
    # Then query for access keys, and use the key creation data to determine key expiration
    for row in credential_report:
        if row['password_enabled'] != "true": continue # Skip IAM Users without passwords, they are service accounts

        message = "" # This is what we send to the user

        if  is_user_expired(row['user']) == 0:
            # Process their password
            password_expires = days_till_expire(row['password_last_changed'], max_age)
            if password_expires <= 0:
                REPORT_SUMMARY = REPORT_SUMMARY + "\n{}'s Password expired {} days ago".format(row['user'], password_expires * -1)
                message = message + expired_message.format(password_expires * -1)
                add_user_to_blackhole(row['user'], iam_client)
            elif password_expires < GRACE_PERIOD :
                message = message + password_warn_message.format(password_expires)
                REPORT_SUMMARY = REPORT_SUMMARY + "\n{}'s Password Will expire in {} days".format(row['user'], password_expires)

        try:
            # Process their Access Keys
            response = iam_client.list_access_keys( UserName=row['user'] )
            for key in response['AccessKeyMetadata'] :
                if key['Status'] == "Inactive" : continue
                key_expires = days_till_expire(key['CreateDate'], max_age)
                if key_expires <= 0:
                    message = message + key_expired_message.format(key['AccessKeyId'], key_expires * -1)
                    disable_users_key(key['AccessKeyId'], row['user'], iam_client)
                    REPORT_SUMMARY = REPORT_SUMMARY + "\n {}'s Key {} expired {} days ago ".format(row['user'], key['AccessKeyId'], key_expires * -1 )
                elif key_expires < GRACE_PERIOD:
                    message = message + key_warn_message.format(key['AccessKeyId'], key_expires)
                    REPORT_SUMMARY = REPORT_SUMMARY + "\n {}'s Key {} will expire {} days from now ".format(row['user'], key['AccessKeyId'], key_expires)
        except ClientError as e:
            continue



        # Email user if necessary
        if message != "": 
            email_user(row['user'], message, account_name)

    # All Done. Send a summary to the ACTION_TOPIC_ARN, and print one out for the Lambda Logs
    print("Action Summary:" + ACTION_SUMMARY)
    if ACTION_SUMMARY != "": send_summary()
    if REPORT_SUMMARY != "": email_user(FROM_ADDRESS, REPORT_SUMMARY, account_name )
    return

def is_user_expired(username):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    try:
        response = client.list_groups_for_user(UserName=username)
    except ClientError as e:
        return 1

    for group in response['Groups'] :
        if group['GroupName'] == BLACKHOLE_GROUPNAME:
            return 1
    return 0


def email_user(email, message, account_name):
    global ACTION_SUMMARY # This is what we send to the admins
    if SEND_EMAIL != "true": return # Abort if we're not supposed to send email
    if message == "": return # Don't send an empty message
    client = boto3.client('ses')
    body = EXPLANATION_HEADER + "\n" + message + "\n\n" + EXPLANATION_FOOTER
    try: 
        response = client.send_email(
            Source=FROM_ADDRESS,
            Destination={ 'ToAddresses': [ email ] },
            Message={
                'Subject': { 'Data': email_subject.format(account_name) },
                'Body': { 'Text': { 'Data': body } }
            }
        )
        ACTION_SUMMARY = ACTION_SUMMARY + "\nEmail Sent to {}".format(email)
        return
    except ClientError as e:
        print("Failed to send message to {}: {}".format(email, e.message))
        ACTION_SUMMARY = ACTION_SUMMARY + "\nERROR: Message to {} was rejected: {}".format(email, e.message)

def days_till_expire(last_changed, max_age):
    # Ok - So last_changed can either be a string to parse or already a datetime object.
    # Handle these accordingly
    if type(last_changed) is str:
        last_changed_date=dateutil.parser.parse(last_changed).date()
    elif type(last_changed) is datetime.datetime:
        last_changed_date=last_changed.date()
    else:
        # print("last_changed", last_changed)
        # print(type(last_changed))
        return -99999
    expires = (last_changed_date + datetime.timedelta(max_age)) - datetime.date.today()
    return(expires.days)


# Request the credential report, download and parse the CSV.
def get_credential_report(iam_client):
    resp1 = iam_client.generate_credential_report()
    if resp1['State'] == 'COMPLETE' :
        try: 
            response = iam_client.get_credential_report()
            credential_report_csv = response['Content']
            # print(credential_report_csv)
            reader = csv.DictReader(credential_report_csv.splitlines())
            # print(reader.fieldnames)
            credential_report = []
            for row in reader:
                credential_report.append(row)
            return(credential_report)
        except ClientError as e:
            print("Unknown error getting Report: " + e.message)
    else:
        sleep(2)
        return get_credential_report(iam_client)

# Query the account's password policy for the password age. Return that number of days
def get_max_password_age(iam_client):
    try: 
        response = iam_client.get_account_password_policy()
        return response['PasswordPolicy']['MaxPasswordAge']
    except ClientError as e:
        print("Unexpected error in get_max_password_age: %s" + e.message) 

# if called by an IAM Event, do stuff. Not yet implemented
def process_IAMEvent(event, context, iam_client):

    api_call = event['detail']['eventName']
    if api_call == "CreateLoginProfile" :
        process_CreateLoginProfile(event,context)
        return 0
    elif api_call == "EnableMFADevice" :
        process_EnableMFADevice(event,context)
        return 0
    elif api_call == "DeactivateMFADevice" :
        process_DeactivateMFADevice(event,context)
        return 0
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid API Call: " + api_call)

# Add the user to the group that only allows them to reset their password
def add_user_to_blackhole(username, iam_client):
    if DISABLE_USERS != "true": return
    global ACTION_SUMMARY
    ACTION_SUMMARY = ACTION_SUMMARY + "\nAdding {} to Blackhole Group".format(username)
    response = iam_client.add_user_to_group(
        GroupName=os.environ['BLACKHOLE_GROUPNAME'],
        UserName=username
    )
    if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] != 200:
        handle_error("Adding User to Blackhole Group", username, response['ResponseMetadata'])
    else: 
        return 0

# Turn off the specified user's key by setting it to inactive. 
def disable_users_key(AccessKeyId, UserName, iam_client):
    if DISABLE_USERS != "true": return
    global ACTION_SUMMARY
    ACTION_SUMMARY = ACTION_SUMMARY + "\nDisabling AccessKeyId {} for user {}".format(AccessKeyId, UserName)
    response = iam_client.update_access_key(
        UserName=UserName,
        AccessKeyId=AccessKeyId,
        Status='Inactive'
    )
    if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] != 200:
        handle_error("Adding User to Blackhole Group", username, response['ResponseMetadata'])
    else: 
        return 0

# Not used, but would remove the user from the blackhole group once they did change their password
def remove_user_from_blackhole(username, iam_client):
    response = iam_client.remove_user_from_group(
        GroupName=os.environ['BLACKHOLE_GROUPNAME'],
        UserName=username
    )
    if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] != 200:
        handle_error("Removing User from Blackhole Group", username, response['ResponseMetadata'])
    else: 
        return 0

def handle_error(action, username, ResponseMetadata):
    raise Exception("ERROR" + action + " User: " + username + " Details: " + ResponseMetadata)

# Send the Summary of actions taken to the SNS topic
def send_summary():
    global ACTION_SUMMARY
    client = boto3.client('sns')

    message = "The following Actions were taken by the Expire Users Script at {}: ".format( datetime.datetime.now() ) + ACTION_SUMMARY

    response = client.publish(
        TopicArn=ACTION_TOPIC_ARN,
        Message=message,
        Subject="Expire Users Report for {}".format(datetime.date.today())
    )
```

Sorry, if its repeated. Couldn't find a solution. If someone has script to notify IAM Users about their password expiry, that would be fine as well.

Thank You.

Comment: I guess the problem is probably in `get_credential_report`. Think what will happen if `resp1['State']` is not `COMPLETE`. You'll effectively keep running `resp1 = iam_client.generate_credential_report()` again and again trying to generate a new report each time. I think what you probably meant to do was keep checking for the state to be complete without restarting the process of generating the report.

Comment: @RobBricheno Thanks for the comment. Could You please let me know what should be the solution.

Comment: If you must obtain the credential report to produce a meaningful reponse, probably replace the `if resp1['State'] == 'COMPLETE' :`  with something like `while resp1['State'] !='COMPLETE':\n    sleep(2)\n (then outside the sleep loop) do stuff with completed resp1` (if that makes sense)

Comment: @RobBricheno Tried,but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the memory, if you ran out of memory you are also getting that message.